# Crash Only in iPod

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, autolayout

The `CRASH` is:

> **This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.**

It is clear that the problem is that every time the ui is changed must be done on the main thread. In theory this might work

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // code here
})
```

My Function is:

```
- (void)requestInBlock:(NSString *)keyThumbnails withArrayQuantity:(NSMutableArray *)quantityArray andOriginalQuantity:(NSInteger)originalQuantity
{
    int limit = 5;

    NSMutableArray *arrayFive = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger idQuantityOriginalCount = [quantityArray count];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < MIN(limit, idQuantityOriginalCount); i ++) {
        [arrayFive addObject:[quantityArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [quantityArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSInteger idLimitArrayCount = [arrayFive count];

    NSInteger __block countProductsRequestLimit = 0;
    for (NSNumber *j in arrayFive) {
        UIImageView * thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xposThumbnails, 0, ratio * 2, 47)];
        [thumbnailsView addSubview:thumbnailImageView];

        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/%@_%@.jpg",keyThumbnails,j]];

        [Utils loadFromURL:imageUrl callback:^(UIImage *image) {

            countProductsRequestLimit++;
            countThumbnailsGlobal++;

            [thumbnailImageView setImage:image];
            [cutVideoScroll addSubview:thumbnailsView];

            if (!image) {
                NSMutableDictionary *collectInfoFailImage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [collectInfoFailImage setValue:thumbnailImageView forKey:@"image"];
                [collectInfoFailImage setValue:imageUrl forKey:@"imageUrl"];
                [thumbnailsWithError addObject:collectInfoFailImage];
                collectInfoFailImage = nil;
            }
            if (countThumbnailsGlobal == originalQuantity) {
                [arrayFive removeAllObjects];
                [self performSelector:@selector(reloadThumbnailsWithError) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
            } else if (idLimitArrayCount == countProductsRequestLimit) {
                [arrayFive removeAllObjects];
                [self requestInBlock:keyThumbnails withArrayQuantity:quantityArray andOriginalQuantity:originalQuantity];
            }
        }];

        xposThumbnails += (ratio * 2);
    }
    loadingTimeLine.layer.zPosition = -1;
    lblloadingTimeLine.layer.zPosition = -1;
}
```

I think the mistake is happening here `loadFromURL`. (***It is not sure about this, because in all devices with I do my tests, this never happens, someone outside informed me and sent me error logs***)

> My question is:

- which part of this code may be modifying the autoLayout, maybe `[cutVideoScroll addSubview:thumbnailsView];`?
- Why only occurs on an iPod?

***UPDATE:***

I'm testing with.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [thumbnailImageView setImage:image];
   [cutVideoScroll addSubview:thumbnailsView];
});
```

But error persist.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a combination of 2 things.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [thumbnailImageView setImage:image];
   [cutVideoScroll addSubview:thumbnailsView];
});
```

and in all cases, he was added to `thumbnailImageView` the `image` regardless validation `if (! image)`

Answer (score 0):

You got it right, adding subview to view trigger `layoutSubviews`. So you should addViews only in main thread.

Maybe you have some code specifically for iPhone / iPod in any method which you override?